# Couple or torque

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction, torque

In the solution of Problem 527, over [here](https://www.mathalino.com/reviewer/engineering-mechanics/problem-527-friction),

> A homogeneous cylinder 3 m in diameter and weighing 30 kN is resting on two inclined planes as shown in Fig. P-527. If the angle of friction is 15° for all contact surfaces, compute the magnitude of the couple required to start the cylinder rotating counterclockwise.
>
> [image]

we have been asked to find out the magnitude of the **couple**.

But, AFAIK, a [couple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Couple_(mechanics)) is produced *only* as a result of two **anti-parallel** forces, of **equal** magnitude, not passing through the same line-of-action.

Incidentally, in their solution, they seemed to have plainly found out the net [**torque**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torque) about the center.

Finding the torque (and the entire solution) is perfectly understandable but then torque is hardly equivalent to couple.

Any help/hint is welcome :-)

Comment: Please take a minute to read our [guidelines for homework and exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) as well as [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093). We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and we prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: Is your question about the use of terminology, or about solving the problem?

Comment: @emilio Well, I am seeking some conceptual clarification on the confusing use of terminologies of torque, couple and moment esp. that something seems to vary between the usage in physics and Mech. Eng. I understand the specific calculations of the linked problem very well but to me except that the solution looks like an answer to a question that asks to find the net torque about the center. Overall, a generalization and some comments as to the problem will be welcome:-)

Comment: Incidentally, calling that text a "solution" really stretches that term to near breaking point. Collections of formulae are **not** the same thing as a solution, without the intervening and linking text that explains what each formula does and how it connects to the rest of the calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task set in the problem

> compute the magnitude of the couple required to start the cylinder rotating counterclockwise

explicitly assumes that the cylinder is being acted on by a couple. This means that you just need to quantify how strong that couple needs to be to get the cylinder to rotate. And more importantly, **the only actual quantitative measure of the strength of a couple is the torque it imparts**. This then includes as a consequence that your assertion that

> torque is hardly equivalent to couple

is just wrong. It is possible for situations to have unbalanced forces where you have both a total force and a total torque, but if the forces are balanced and you have a couple then the magnitude of the couple is nothing less and nothing more than the total torque it imparts.

This is where it seems that your core misconception is coming from.

> But, AFAIK, a couple is produced only as a result of two anti-parallel forces, of equal magnitude, not passing through the same line-of-action.

The question *doesn't care* how the couple is imparted - what the forces are, whether they're two or three or more, and what their lines of action are. It just knows that there are forces acting on the cylinder with zero total force and nonzero total torque (a.k.a. a couple), and it wants to figure out whether those forces will beat the friction or not. The internal details of the couple are irrelevant - the only thing that determines whether it will beat the friction or not is the total torque, i.e. the magnitude of the couple.

Comment: Many thanks for the lucid explanation, though I can't up-vote it:( The most salient point was _nonzero total torque (a.k.a. a couple)_ :-) Will be accepting in a while.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confused about the implications of a moment couple.

The moment couple is useful in part because it is the equivalent of applying a *pure moment* on a rigid body.  You should be able to see that pretty easily by looking at the net force and net moment of a rigid body that has a force couple acting on it.  Work out how a body will react to a moment couple compared to a pure moment or torque.  It should make perfect sense why the example was done that way.

Honestly, I would suggest skimming the Wikipedia page on [Couples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Couple_(mechanics)).  It seems to address many of the misconceptions.